# Type Members and Value Members of a Scala Class

Tags: scala

In Scala, classes can have Type Members and Value Members, I am just wondering what is the difference between these two and when would you use one of these.

Comment: It's important to realize that Scala's `type` keyword only introduces a new name (or family of names, if parameterized) for already existing types.

Answer (score 5):

Value members (or rather term members) are class members that represent some value.
These are: `def`s, `val`s, `var`s and inner `object`s.

Type members are members that represent a type. These are inner classes, traits and abstract types or type aliases (declared or defined with keyword `type`).

```
abstract class A {
  // examples of term members
  val someVal = 5
  var someVar = 0
  def someMethod(someParam: Int) = someParam * 2
  object someInnerObject

  // examples of type members
  type SomeTypeAlias = List[String]
  type SomeAbstractType
  trait SomeInnerTrait
  class SomeInnerClass
}
```

I don't know if there is anything more significant to say about this classification. I hope someone can give some more general explanation if there is one.

Comment: Basically, type members are members which are types, and value members are members which are values. I really don't think there's anything more to say about that, unless the OP provides a concrete problem.